# Where are \ { and } on an Apple Wireless Keyboard - French?

Tags: keyboard

I am using an [Apple Wireless Keyboard - French](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MC184F/B).

Could anyone tell me how to type <kbd>\</kbd> <kbd>{</kbd> and <kbd>}</kbd>?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- \ = <kbd>Option ⌥</kbd> + <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd> + <kbd>:</kbd>
- { = <kbd>Option ⌥</kbd> + <kbd>(</kbd>
- } = <kbd>Option ⌥</kbd> + <kbd>)</kbd>

You can display the layout in the Preferences (Language & Text - Input Sources - Show Input Sources in Menu bar).